# How can I promisify a simple asynchronous function I wrote?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

## Setup

While writing some numerical Javascript code for Node, the thought occurred, "Why not make this asynchronous?" E.g.,

```
var mySquare = function(x, callback) {
    callback(null, x * x);
}

mySquare(3, function(err, res) { console.log(res); });
// prints 9
```

except with a much more complex calculation, and one that might throw an error.

## Question

How do I promisify this function, without rewriting it to use promises? Using [bluebird's promisify](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyfunction-nodefunction--dynamic-receiver---function), via `var promisedSquare = Promise.promisify(mySquare)`, returns an error stack:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at l (/path/bluebird.min.js:30:15474)
    at Function.e.promisify (/path/bluebird.min.js:30:16031)
    at repl:1:30
...
```

It almost looks like bluebird tried to evaluate `mySquare`. I've had no trouble promisifying library functions like `d3.json` (which wraps XHR), so I'm confused: do I need to provide bluebird with anything more than a callback-driven asynchronous function?

Comment: Continuation passing style is not necessarily asynchronous.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. Probably you are doing `Promise.promisify(mySquare(..))`. Check this [REPL Demo](https://asciinema.org/a/b37uybr5uuywk9jvfylglpg7d)

Comment: Using callbacks doesn't make automatically make your code asynchronous. And using them adds unnecessary complication/confusion if the function isn't doing anything async (such as network, disk I/O, using timers etc).

Comment: @thefourtheye is right, my node must have not been correctly set up with bluebird. Works in the browser and after `npm install -save bluebird`, works in node as well. Sorry for the pointless post!

Comment: @AhmedFasih But as others pointed out, you don't have to Promisify this, as the function would still be executed synchronously.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I must have made an error in logic when reading explanations of async/CPS that stressed the importance of avoiding blocking when doing something time-consuming. Apparently the converse isn't true: I can't magically avoid blocking via CPS. Is there any way that I can reap the benefits of asynchronous programming for such tasks?

Comment: Anything that requires CPU such as arithmetic is going to be blocking.  You can only unblock for i/o (things such as interacting with the network [databases, http] or file system).  If you have a multi-core system you want to use, you can use child processes.

Comment: Not with a single core. If the CPU is busy, it's busy. If this were a really heavy computation you could look at offloading it onto other processes/machines.

Comment: @AhmedFasih: The only way to make your function asynchronous is to call  asynchronous functions. Fortunately, javascript provides a function for exactly this: `setTimeout(function(){},0)`. In node.js that is roughly the same as `process.nextTick(function(){})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who commented: I'll condense your elucidations into an answer to close this question.

The error must have been a node misconfiguration on my part, since the code snippet worked in the browser, and after an npm reinstall, in node too.

But the question highlighted a flawed understanding of asynchronous operations vs continuation-passing style. I now understand that the Javascript runtime can only hide the latencies of disk or network fetches, or more generally, when it's waiting on something other than itself. If the runtime has to do a large computation, that's all it can do: it won't be able to magically pause a numerical calculation mid-step to service, say, web requests.

Comment: …except you explicitly tell it to pause, by using an asynchronous timeout.